# Different php include by date

Tags: php, date, include

I have 365 php pages already created for next year currently named:

- 1-1-2015.php
- 1-2-2015.php
- 1-3-2015.php

I want to display a different one each day using `<?php include("1-1-2015.php"); ?>` on my home page, I have curenlty done somthing similar for days of the week using "if else"

```
<?php 
$today = date("l");
if($today == "Sunday") 
{
//do Sunday Thing
}
elseif($today == "Monday")
{
// do Monday Thing
} 
?>
```

Is there a better way to do this other than 365 if statements as i would like this to be future proof so it would just be a case of adding the next 365 pages in 2016?

Comment: Something like `include(date("n-j-Y").".php");`?

Comment: One include file for each day? That looks like a very bad (and lazy) approach. I think you should restructure your application.

Comment: Why do you have 365 php files?  What are you doing?  Can't you just dynamically generate them on the fly?

Comment: I never even thought of that, Its a completely customized page everyday, so i cant create it on the fly as, everything will be differnent even the CSS and Js files.

Comment: and what varies between each of the 365 pages? php is actually quite good at producing dynamic content

Comment: @Ma9ic Why do you want 365 pages? What are you doing differently on each one?

Comment: Wait so... What are you going to do in 2016?

Comment: @jimbo the pages are fully unique and customized and are submitted each day by a different team member and will have no repeated patterns from day to day.

Comment: @secondRikudo each team/member will resubmit a new page each year. Its only for internal use :)

Comment: @Ma9ic Fair enough. What is on those pages? Trying to figure out how you can do this with *one file*, as you most likely *can*.

Comment: @jimbo there going to be adding custom / css and javascript to show case what there working one.

Comment: @Ma9ic Sounds like something for a single file and a database holding all the information that changes :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `date()` to format the date to match your file naming scheme.

```
$filename = sprintf('%s.php', date('n-j-Y'));
include($filename);
```

Comment: It looks like his format is `n-j-Y`, but it's a little ambiguous ;)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I believe you are correct. Fixed. Thanks for the heads up.